# close responsive menu when clicked/touch off

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have managed to get the menu to close when you click/touch outside of the menu but how do I stop the menu from closing when a link (within that menu) is clicked?

Here is my javascript:

```
            jQuery(document).click(function (event) {
                var clickover = jQuery(event.target);
                var _opened = jQuery(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in");
                if (_opened === true && !clickover.is('.bs-navbar-collapse') && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
                    jQuery("button.navbar-toggle").click();
                }
            });
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4):

Stop event bubbling if it originates from navbar

```
jQuery(document).click(function(event) {
    var clickover = jQuery(event.target);
    var _opened = jQuery(".navbar-collapse").hasClass("in");
    if (_opened === true && !clickover.is('.bs-navbar-collapse') && !clickover.hasClass("navbar-toggle")) {
        jQuery("button.navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});

jQuery(".dropdown-menu").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that this makes the drop down menu within not work :-(

Comment: Can you post your HTML so I could take a look?

Comment: It's just a standard bootstrap menu with a nested list/dropdown-menu under one of the main nav links

Comment: Check updated answer, I guess you need to stop bubbling for `.dropdown-menu` element.

Comment: Nothing happens. The drop down links still do not work/expand.

Comment: Okay, here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rB5dNxeLqVbJaCXLCB9o?p=info Adjust it to your case and post it here. Otherwise I'm just trying to guess.

Comment: Here is my version. The problem I have is that when you click on the submenu link 'Action' the submenu closes. This link will be a modal window btw thus why I wish to keep that menu open. 

http://plnkr.co/edit/arGrZ8onXsHYNjAIOeQx?p=preview